# What is the intersection between $x + y - z = -2$ and $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, conic-sections

I got the answer as $4x + 4y + 2xy + 4 = 0$ by substituting $z = x + y + 2$ into the second equation, but I feel as this is wrong since I am missing $z$ in the function.
How do I approach this problem?

Comment: yes you'll miss $z$ since you are substituting value of $z$.And moreover your intersection will be a 2 dimensional figure.

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal the intersection will not be 2-dimensional, rather we have a cone intersected with a plane, so the intersection will be some conic section living in the given plane.

Comment: @msteve yes that's a ellipse in the plane which is 2 dimensional that's why $z$ is missing.

Comment: then how do I approach this problem? how would I find the intersection so that z is not missing?

Comment: Why do you want to find the intersection such that $z$ is not missing? You see that you're intersecting a surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$ with a plane so the curve you get( ellipse here) will lie inside the plane and thus will be dependent on two variables which are $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, as you have substituted in the value of $z$, you will get an equation in terms of $x \text { and } y$. Here is what it looks like:

[image: nothing]

As you can see, there are infinitely many points of intersection of $x + y - z = -2$ and $z^2=x^2+y^2$ (where the white plane intersects the red cone). The green part shows $4x + 4y + 2xy + 4 = 0$. If you want to find the $z$-coordinates then plug in the values of $x$ and $y$ into either equation. Hope that this helps, despite being $3$ years too late.